# How to pass body with Google APIs Client Library?

Tags: python, google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-python-client

I use [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) to work with [Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started). [importRows](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.table.importRows) method here requires to provide the data in the body. How should I do it?

```
response = service.table().importRows(tableId=TABLE_ID, body='zzz,yyy').execute()
```

returns the error - `Got an unexpected keyword argument "body"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slight subtlety here -- the body of the [request](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows) should be the `Table` resource, if you want to update it; the *contents* (in this case, the rows) should actually be passed as a media upload.

In the python client, this means you want to pass something in to the `media_body` argument, *not* `body`. You can't just pass a literal string -- you need to wrap the data in either a [MediaFileUpload](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L381) or [MediaInMemoryUpload](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L444). (For the case here, you want the latter, but if you've got a file with rows on disk, you want the former.)