# Using importRows to upload FusionTables data fails with HttpError 500: Backend Error

Tags: python, google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-python-client

I am using [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) to update a Fusion Table and add rows to a Fusion Table with the Fusion Tables API v1. I can do this successfully when I do it one row at a time using the SQL INSERT query method.  I would also like to be able to update the Fusion Table using the `importRows` method.

I start with a file 'testCsv.csv' and would like to import it completely into an existing Fusion Table.  There is a good conceptual explanation of doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801255/how-to-pass-body-with-google-apis-client-library).

The conceptual example explains if the API accepted images, but to update a Fusion Table, the type must be 'application/octet-stream'.

I have tried to use the `importRows` method with the following code (note: `service` is an authenticated API connection):

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
.
.
.
mediaCsv=MediaFileUpload(csvFileName, mimetype='application/octet-stream')
request = service.table().importRows(tableId=wrrTweetsID, media_body=mediaCsv,
            startLine=1, encoding='auto-detect')
response = request.execute()
```

When I execute this code I get back this error message:

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/--table_id--/import?uploadType=media&alt=json&startLine=1&encoding=auto-detect"
  returned "Backend Error">
```

My question is, do I need to do something to the `.csv` to convert it to `application/octet-stream`?  Or is there something else I am missing in using this method?

Answer (score 4):

Since posting this question, I have learned that `application/octet-stream` is similar to saying that the type is anything.  I have also figured out what was wrong with my use of `importRows`.  The [method documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows) indicates that

> "Default is UTF-8. Use `'auto-detect'` if you are unsure of the encoding."

I assumed that using `'auto-detect'` was the safest way to make sure my request was received correctly. That was an incorrect assumption: changing the encoding to be `'utf-8'` resulted in a successful `importRows` request.